# Get Running Totals EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

everything fine ?
I have the following problem ... I have the following data according to the model below

| Id | CreatedDate | Name | TypeTransaction | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/04/2021 10:00:00 | Item A | IN | 2 |
| 2 | 01/04/2021 10:30:00 | Item A | OUT | 1 |
| 3 | 01/04/2021 07:00:00 | Item B | IN | 1 |
| 4 | 02/04/2021 15:00:00 | Item A | IN | 1 |
| 5 | 01/04/2021 12:00:00 | Item C | IN | 1 |
| 6 | 02/04/2021 08:00:00 | Item B | OUT | 1 |
| 7 | 01/04/2021 13:00:00 | Item C | INT | 1 |
| 8 | 03/04/2021 16:00:00 | Item A | INT | 3 |

I need to group this data where I will have an additional Balance column according to the date of the transaction, sorted by date and description of the item. It should be approximately in this model below. How can I do this using LINQ?

**Desired output:**

| Id | CreatedDate | Name | TypeTransaction | Quantity | **Balance** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/04/2021 10:00:00 | Item A | IN | 2 | **2** |
| 2 | 01/04/2021 10:00:30 | Item A | OUT | 1 | **1** |
| 4 | 02/04/2021 15:00:00 | Item A | IN | 1 | **2** |
| 8 | 03/04/2021 16:00:00 | Item A | IN | 3 | **5** |
| 3 | 01/04/2021 07:00 00 | Item B | IN | 1 | **1** |
| 6 | 02/04/2021 08:00:00 | Item B | OUT | 1 | **0** |
| 5 | 01/04/2021 12:00:00 | Item C | INT | 1 | **1** |
| 7 | 03/04/2021 13:00:00 | Item C | INT | 1 | **2** |

Comment: Not aware of any way to do it with EF Linq, especially with positive values for IN and OUT. you may need to query the data and calculate the balance based on the results. That may require additional queries if the data is to be paginated rather than a complete list.  One other option would be to write a View in SQL to provide the running total and bind a read only entity for the output to that. Google-fu "SQL Partition running total" for ideas on setting that query up. (If it's an interview question, it's a good one! :)

Comment: Thx a lot Steve, now i made a view in SQL as you suggested and i managed to get the desired result.